# Why is this JAX jitted function so much slower than the non-jitted JAX version?

Tags: python, numpy, time, jit, jax

I'm in the process of rewriting some code from pure Python to JAX. I have a function that I need to call a lot. Why is the jitted version of the following function so much slower than the non-jitted version?

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import jit

def regular(M,R,a):
    return (3+a)*M*R**a / (4*jnp.pi * R**(3+a))

@jit
def jitted(M,R,a):
    return (3+a)*M*R**a / (4*jnp.pi * R**(3+a))

%timeit regular(1e10,100.,-2.)
# 346 ns ± 2.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

%timeit jitted(1e10,100.,-2.)
# 4.2 µs ± 10.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some helpful information on benchmarking in JAX's FAQ: [Benchmarking JAX Code](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#benchmarking-jax-code): in particular note the discussion of JAX dispatch overhead for individual operations.

Regarding your particular example, the first thing to point out is that you're not comparing jit-compiled JAX code against non-jit-compiled JAX code; you're comparing jit-compiled JAX code against *pure Python* code. Because you're passing python scalars to the function, none of the operations in `regular` have anything to do with JAX (even `jnp.pi` is just a Python float), so you're just executing built-in Python arithmetic operators on Python scalars.

If you want to compare JAX jit to non-jit code, you can use JAX values rather than scalar values as inputs; for example:

```py
a = jnp.array(1e10)
b = jnp.array(100.)
c = jnp.array(-2.)

%timeit regular(a, b, c).block_until_ready()
# 86.8 µs ± 1.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit jitted(a, b, c).block_until_ready()
# 3.71 µs ± 59.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Here you see that JIT gives you about a 20x speedup over un-jitted JAX code.

But JIT or not, why is JAX so much slower than the native Python version? The reason is because each JAX function call incurs a few microseconds of dispatch overhead, while each native Python operation has much less dispatch overhead. You've written a function where the actual computations are so small they are virtually free; to first order all you are measuring is dispatch overhead.

In situations JAX was designed for (executing JIT-compiled sequences of operations over large arrays on accelerators), this one-time, few-microsecond dispatch cost is generally not significant in comparison to the full computation.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the clarification! Regarding "each JAX function call incurs a few milliseconds of dispatch overhead" -- do you mean few microseconds? Because the %timeit results for the JAX (jit or no-jit) are of order microseconds, not milliseconds.